Speeding up Brython with WebAssembly compiled from Rust
I want to speed up brython code with webassembly functions. It appears I can properly use the wasm functions in javascript code, but for brython I would need to assign them to window. That in itself looks to be the main issue, but if there is a better way then assigning things to window, please share. I am still learning html, js and rust so yeah, be mindful of that xD.
Here is what I am currently working with:
<!Doctype html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta charset = "utf-8"> 
    <script type = "text/javascript"
        src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/brython@3.8.9/brython.min.js"> 
    </script> 
</head>
<script type="module">
    import init, {add_wasm} from './pkg/hello_wasm.js';
    await init();
    console.log(add_wasm(3,4))
    window.wasmfunc = add_wasm();
</script>
<body onload = "brython()"> 
<script type = "text/python"> 
from browser import window
result = window.wasmfunc(3, 5)
print(result)
</script> 
</body> 
</html>

As far as I know, I need to have a function assigned to window for it to be available in brython code. I have tested it and indeed a pure js function can be executed that way. However in this example there is an AtributeError no attribute wasmfunc for [object Window]. The console.log gives me 7 in the console so I know the wasm function works properly, however it appears only after the brython error, which I suppose could mean the brython code is executed first somehow? Could you tell me how can I get this to work?
